# Fill a JComboBox with new values

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

currently I am filling my JComboBox like that:

```
countryBox = new JComboBox(countryList.toArray(new String[countryList.size()]));
```

However, when using my program the `countryList` changes and I would like to fill my JComboBox differently. I tried to use the action to change my JComboBox:

```
countryBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   countryBox = new JComboBox(countryList.toArray(new String[countryList.size()]));
}
```

However, it does not change its values. For me it seems that the countryBox is prefilled with the data from before. Any recommendations what I could do?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 7):

Don't create a new `JComboBox`, create a new model

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(countryList.toArray(new String[countryList.size()]));
countryBox.setModel(model);
```

You could create your own `ComboBoxModel` which could proxy you current `List`, but that's up to you.

Take a closer look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details