# How to add ArrayList in Netbeans default comboboxmodel?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox, netbeans-8

I created a program using netbeans form editor. I added combo box on it.
which has default code.

```
comPortComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] 
      { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
```

But I want to modify the list of an item in custome mode using my own List:

```
List<String> comPortList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So,

How can I put my comPortList inside the combobox without using comPortComboBox.removeAllItems() and comPortComboBox.addItem() ?

Comment: Short answer is to create a new model and apply it to the combo box

Comment: As is demonstrated in @MadProgrammer's answer in the question used to close this current question as a dup.

Comment: And also [demonstrated here, slightly differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358545/fill-a-jcombobox-with-new-values/25358592#25358592)

Comment: Thanks everyone, haha.